# transfer of php data to xcode app

Tags: php, xcode

I'm trying to transfer data between a php page made on my site and a NSData object in an xcode project I wrote. The php page is very simple it gets:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr">
        <head>
             <title>Mon MEGA BLOG</title>
             <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
         </head>
         <style type="text/css">
    form
         {
             text-align:center;
         }
    </style>


    <body>

<?php echo 'Bonjour'; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like the 'Bonjour' to be transferred to my data object. There is no question from this time to send specific objects through $_GET method (although it has been prepared in the below code). I just want to test the response of my php page with the echo function. My xcode project goes:

```
if(![loginText.text isEqualToString:@""] && ![passwordText.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        //1. creation de la request
        NSMutableString *string = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:200];
        NSString *string01 = @"http://attheshop.fr/index.php?prof=&pass="; 

        [string appendFormat:string01];
      NSString *string02 = loginText.text;
      NSString *string03 = passwordText.text;

        [string insertString:string03 atIndex:41];
        [string insertString:string02 atIndex:36];

        request01 =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:string]cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

        NSLog(@"%@", string);
        //2.creation de la connection et start loading data

       NSURLConnection *connection01 = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request01 delegate:self];

       if(connection01)
       {
        //3.Create NSMutableData to receive data
        receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
           NSLog(@"Voici ce que contient le message %@", receivedData.description); 
        }

    } 
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    // This method is called when the server has determined that it // has enough information to create the NSURLResponse.
    // It can be called multiple times, for example in the case of a // redirect, so each time we reset the data.
    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    // Append the new data to receivedData. // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere. 
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    // release the connection, and the data object 
    // inform the user 

    NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",[error localizedDescription], [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);

    //set an alert
    UIAlertView *alert01 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Probleme de connexion" message:@"La connexion a échoué" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Recommençer" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    alert01.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleDefault;
    [alert01 show];
}


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    // do something with the data // receivedData is declared as a method instance elsewhere 

    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[receivedData length]);

    //6.Mettre les informations téléchargées dans un objet data envoyé à home.

    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request01 returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    //NSLog(@"response %@", response.description);

    NSString *get = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"get %@", get.description);

    NSString *string04 = @"error";
    NSPredicate *errorTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS %@", string04];
    BOOL defError = [errorTest evaluateWithObject:get];

    NSLog(@"%i",defError);

    if (!defError) 
    {
        //Si pas d'erreur, on lance le segue
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginMainSegue" sender:self];
    }

    //5.Si mauvais login ou password message alerte erreur

    if (defError) 
    {
        UIAlertView *alert02 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Erreur" message:@"Votre login ou votre password est erroné" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Recommençer" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        alert02.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleDefault;
        [alert02 show];        
    }

}
```

I would like to know why the response object contains the whole php page, and not the only word that should be displayed, 'Bonjour'.

thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the PHP bit, remove everything else on the page that's not PHP. The request you're making gets everything in that HTTP request, not just the PHP bit. That includes the HTML that you have on the page.

Alternatively, use JSON to move data around. `json_encode()` it from the PHP side, and then use something like JSONKit to decode it on the Xcode side.